# Android Policy: External application files

Tags: java, android, flash, dynamic, external

[Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) says:

> An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update
>   its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's
>   update mechanism.

I want to publish my application to Google Play. And I been planing to load my core **SWF file** dynamically, so game updates could be done without the need of going to Google Play market. An alternative Java implementation can achieve the same thing by downloading remote **jar file**.

In both cases I will have the next limitations:

1. I cannot modify my Manifest file.

   - I cannot extend the application permissions that I asked
2. My external code is bounded to application sand box(Just as the rest of my application)

Notice that my external code is not part of the APK files. It will be stored in application folder or in external storage(SD-Card). Its same place where external assets is stored.

Does this violatating Google policy? I am not sure what they meant by *"APK binary code"*.

Comment: "so game updates could be done without the need of going to Google Play market" Why do you want to do that? Updating via Google Play is the way users are accustomed to (they have notifications, settings, review filtering etc.), and it can be done automatically.

Comment: @MártonMolnár Sometimes you release a version and you do not want to add backward compatibility, so you can't allow users to choose not updating the application. Google Play store do not support such enforcement.

Comment: Did you tried? Want do the same, but scared of ban by policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a lawyer. I see this restriction as limiting only the apk binaries. There are many apps that have dynamic behavior changes, for example Google search where the search results algorithm is determined by dynamic code on the server, or facebook which loads new images texts, layouts and more.
I think that as long as you do not do anything bad for users using the swf changes, you should be ok. 
The purpose of this clause, as I  understand it, is to prevent apps from loading and using code that was not tested by Google using the normal process that tests apps when published. Google want to ensure that all code is scanned/tested by their bots.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer, and I don't play one on TV...

Your best course of action is to look at the reason they included that phrase in the first place.  That text now exists in the Google Play policy because [Facebook did the very same thing](http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/15/4107376/facebook-android-app-update-build-141046-not-using-google-play-store) that you are describing in their application (providing an auto-update mechanism outside the Play Store) earlier this year, and Google [threatened banning the application](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/04/google-bans-self-updating-android-apps-possibly-including-facebooks/) until this "feature" was removed (which it was, shortly thereafter).

The **spirit of the law** in this case is that Google does not want applications updating themselves without the user's consent outside of the Play Store...period.  If your application does this, you can bet Google won't care **how** you are doing it and will likely remove the application when and if the feature is discovered.  They won't care how closely executable code in an external SWF file resembles the internal classes of the APK.

Legal language like this is is intentionally vague so companies can apply it in any situation they see fit.  Don't think you're being safe by splitting hairs with the terminology.